# MySQL - How to throw exception in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, exception, stored-procedures

How to generate an exception in the stored procedure in MySQL? For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SALES()
BEGIN

STATEMENT...
STATEMENT...
STATEMENT...

IF (PRICE >= 500) THEN
/** THROWS AN EXCEPTION....  
    WHAT DO TO STOP THE PROCEDURE. **/
END IF;

STATEMENT...
STATEMENT...
STATEMENT...

END;
```

In MySQL I think there is no way to throw an exception in a stored procedure, but I can force an error by selecting from a non-existing table. For example:

```
IF (PRICE > 500) THEN
    /*throw the error here*/
    SELECT * FROM price_greater_than_500_in_throw_exception;
END IF;
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since MySQL 5.5 you can use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) and [RESIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resignal.html) for error handling. Prior to that there was no way to handle errors in MySQL. Only way is to run an erroneous query (for example inserting into non existing table).

Answer (score 27):

Here is an example of how to throw an exception in mysql, which works on versions 5.5 and above:

```sql
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Custom error';
```

Details can be found here: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html)